# Interpretation of yolov5 output

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, object-detection, onnx, yolov5

I am making a face mask detection project and I trained my model using ultralytics/yolov5.I saved the trained model as an onnx file, you can find the model file here [model.onnx](https://github.com/iamarpan/face_mask_detection). Now I want you use this model.onnx with opencv to detect real time face mask. The input image size during training was 320*320. You can visualize this model using netron.
I have written this code to capture the image using webcam and pass it to model.onnx to predict my bounding boxes. The code is as follows:

```
def predict(img):
    session = onnxruntime.InferenceSession(model_path)
    input_name = session.get_inputs()[0].name
    output_name = session.get_outputs()[0].name
    img = img.reshape((1,3,320,320))
    data = json.dumps({'data':img.tolist()})
    data = np.array(json.loads(data)['data']).astype('float32')
    result = session.run([output_name],{input_name:data})
    result = np.array(result)
    print(result.shape)
```

The output of result.shape is (1, 1, 3, 40, 40, 85)
Can anyone help me in interpreting this shape and how can i use this result array to predict my class, bounding box and confidence.

Answer (score 0):

I've never worked with a pure yolov5 model, but here's the output format for yolov5s. It looks like it should be similar.

```
ouput tensor structure (yolov5s):
output_tensor[a, b, c, d]
    a -> image index (If you're input is a batch of images, this tells you which image's output you're looking at. If your input is just one image, leave this as 0.)
    b -> index of image in batch
    c -> information about bounding box
        0, 1 -> x and y coordinate of bounding box center
        2, 3 -> width and height of bounding box
        4 -> bounding box confidence
        5 - 85 -> single class confidences
    d -> index of proposed bounding boxes
```

Comment: where can I find this info ? can you provide a link for the details of the output format ?

Comment: Sorry man, this was over a year ago and it's been a long while since I've needed this information. I don't remember exactly where I got it. but you'll probably be able to find it somewhere on the yolo5 github.